# I'm getting Class Not Found Exception on launching Kafka consumer from command prompt. How do I resolve this?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was executing the Word Count problem using Kafka-streams. Kafka's version used was 2.3.1, created two topics word-count-input and word-count-output. The code for the same is

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "word-count");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("word-count-input");

    KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines.mapValues(value -> value.toLowerCase())
                                               .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(" ")))
                                               .selectKey((key,value) -> value)
                                               .groupByKey()
                                               .count();

    // Writing back to the kafka topic
    wordCounts.toStream().to("word-count-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
    streams.start();


    //printing the topology
    System.out.println(streams.toString());

    // shutdown hook to correctly close the stream application
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));

}
```

On launching a consumer for topic word-count-output using command prompt, it throws Class Not Found Exception for setting properties of key.deserializer and value.deserializer.

You can have a look at the command prompt [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7DgY.png).

Comment: Is it so hard to copy and paste the code instead of taking a screenshot of it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please put text in your question instead of a screenshot. It makes it much easier for people to help you, and for your question to be searched and found to help others in the future. Can you also edit your question to include how you've installed Kafka.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous the screenshot wasn't of the code. It would have been better to have a look first.

Comment: Sounds like a CLASSPATH issue. The question is not about Kafka Streams though and the program code you pasted is not relevant at all. The issue is only for the `bin/kafka-console-consumer.bat` tool.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for your time. Even I thought the code was irrelevant that's why I didn't upload it earlier on. But after reading the first two comments I thought ppl may require it to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the difference in the Kafka version. The installed version on the system was 2.3.1 and the one in maven was 2.1.1. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: As I said: CLASSPATH issue (what often indicates a version miss-match). You might want to mark our own answer as accepted.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Oh thanks, I thought you were referring to the classpath I've set for Kafka and Zookeeper on my system.

Comment: Oh. I see. Sorry for the confusion. I meat that `bin/kafka-console-consumer.bat` is internally building up a wrong classpath, what it indeed did, as it added the wrong version to it's classpath.